# Why docker container is not using all CPU available?

Tags: windows, docker, .net

I'm comparing the performance of an application running within a docker container (windows server image, legacy .NET framework app) against the same application running directly in the host machine.

The test consists of 15 seconds bursts of Web Requests against each target. I'm finding it odd that when I target the host app CPU usage is maxed out (as expected) but when I target the containerized app CPU usage is pretty low even though the container was created without CPU/Memory limits:

[image]

As a result the containerized app is processing much less web requests than the host app.

Is this related to windows images? Any tips on how to make docker use all CPU resources available?

Comment: Possibly related question on SO: [Why are requests taking so long when using docker on Windows 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69990377/why-are-requests-taking-so-long-when-using-docker-on-windows-10)

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/devops/how-to-connect-to-localhost-within-a-docker-container/ if you are connecting to the host network.  "Docker provides a host network which lets containers share your host’s networking stack. This approach means localhost inside a container resolves to the physical host, instead of the container itself."

Comment: Hi @GregAskew! The container wasn't launched with the host network.

Answer (score 0):

So after some more digging I believe I have found the cause of this issue. It seems to be a docker networking related problem. My original burst test was using `localhost` in the containerized app URL:

- http://localhost:8081/docker/webapp

Which somehow was resulting in very large networking delays for GET requests to be served, that's why CPU usage was low.

By simply changing it to `127.0.0.1` the containerized app started performing as expected:

- http://127.0.0.1:8081/docker/webapp

Here's the output of my simple "burst" test. The first entry is the host app, and the following two entries are for the containerized app tested using different URLs:

[image]

The "success count" is the actual number of successful GET requests served in the 15s window. The higher, the better.